# Reducing run time in java

Tags: java

Below Java code produces the valid output but it takes more time to execute. Code works fine in eclipse, but it do not work in an online compiler like hackerrank or hackerearth since it takes more time for execution.Someone help me to find the solution for my time complexity problem.

I have tried to find the solution of the problem but i wasn't able to fix the performance by reducing the time..

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
String s = "aab";
String s1 = "";
String s2 = "";
int n1 = 0;
int length = 0;
long n = 882787;
long count = 0;
while (s1.length() < n) {
    s1 = s1 + s;

}
if (s1.length() > n) {
    count = s1.length() - n;
    n1 = (int) count;
}

for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - n1; i++) {
    if (s1.charAt(i) == 'a') {
        length += 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(length);
```

Explanation of the above program:
  I have a string s,in lowercase English letters that .I have repeat the string for n times and I store it in the new string.
I have to find the number of occurrences of 'a' in my new string

How do i actually reduce the time complexity for the above program

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider running a profiler to see where time is spent.

Comment: You could check your string once of how many `a` chars there are and just multiply it by number of times you have to concat you word.

Comment: Think about whether the `i<s1.length()-n1` condition can be simplified. (This doesn't improve the speed, it just makes some of the code redundant).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to create a `String` based on the initial input consisting of only letter 'a'(s). Take the length of that `String` and multiply it by `n`. That is one line that looks like

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^a]+", "").length() * n);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to add `s` to the string `n/s.length()` times, call this N:

```
int N = n / s.length();
```

Each time you add `s` to the string you are going to append the number of As in `s`:

```
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
  a += s.charAt(i) == 'a' ? 1 : 0;
}
// Or int a = s.replaceAll("[^a]", "").length();
```

So multiple these together:

```
int length = a * N;
```

Comment: Hi sir,suppose if my  n is 10 and and my string s is aba . i have to add the string upto n then my new string s1='abaabaabaa'.total number of occurences of 'a' is 7.but your solution it gave the result of 6

Comment: @karthikeyanGuna ok, well... Can you think how to make use of this approach to get the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable. Modification of a string is in fact create a new String object and put both old and new String into [Java String constant poom](https://study.com/academy/lesson/java-string-constant-pool-concept-mechanism.html)

If you don't want to change your algorithm, I'd suggest to use StringBuilder to improve the speed of the execution. Note that StringBuilder is not thread safe

```
String s="aab";
int n1 = 0;
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
int length=0;
long n=882787;
long count=0;

while(sb1.length() < n) {
    sb1.append(s);
}
if(sb1.length()>n) {
    count =sb1.length()-n;
    n1=(int)count;
}

for(int i=0;i<sb1.length()- n1;i++) {
    if(sb1.charAt(i)=='a') {
        length+=1;
    }
}
System.out.println(length);
```

From [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-vs-stringbuilder-vs-stringbuffer-in-java/)

> When to use which one :
>
> If a string is going to remain constant throughout the program, then
>   use String class object because a String object is immutable. If a
>   string can change (example: lots of logic and operations in the
>   construction of the string) and will only be accessed from a single
>   thread, using a StringBuilder is good enough. If a string can change,
>   and will be accessed from multiple threads, use a StringBuffer because
>   StringBuffer is synchronous so you have thread-safety.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple possible optimizations:

a) One pattern that is not that good is creating lots of Strings through repeated string concatenation. Each "s1 = s1 + s;" creates a new instance of String which will be obsolet the next time the command runs (It increases the load, because the String instances will be additional work for the Garbage Collector).

b) Generally: If you find, that your algorithm takes too long, then you should think about a complete new way to solve the issue. So a different solution could be:
- You know the length you want to have (n) and the length of the small string (s1) that you use to create the big string. So you can calculate: How often will the small string be inside the target string? How many characters are left?
==> You can simply check the small string for the character you are looking for. That multiplied by the number how often the small string will be inside the big string is the first result that you get.
==> Now you need to check the substring of the small string that are missing.

Example: n=10, s1="aab", Looking for "a":
So first we check how often the s1 will fit into a new string of n Characters n/length(s1) => 3
So we check how often the "a" is inside "aab" -> 2
First result is 3*2 = 6
But we checked for 3*3 = 9 characters so far, but we want 10 characters. So we need to check n % length(s1) = 1 character of s1 and in this substring ("a"), wie have 1 a, so we have to add 1.
So the result is 7 which we got without building a big string (which is not required at all!)

Answer (score 0):

Just check how many times the char occurs in the original and multiple it by `n`. Here's a simple way to do so without even using regex:

```
// take these as function input or w/e    
String s = "aab";
String find = "a";
long n = 882787;

int count = s.length() - s.replaceAll(find, "").length();
System.out.println(count * n);
```